# How to Automate or Move (Silverlight) xap file to 14 hive ClientBin

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I am using silverlight project in sharepoint 2010.I have an requirement of using WSP builder project only for building the soultion and I have configured the layout structure depends on 14 hive.

In the dev machine I have configured post build event command in the project properties tab xcopy Sample.xap "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin\" /Y

So whenever I build the silverlight project automatically the sample.xap file will be moved to the 14 hive client bin but when I build WSP for the project using wsp builder the clientbin folder is not available in it. But when I right click the clientbin folder in visual studio solution the sample.xap file is present but inside the wsp it is not there ?

So could you provide a solution for automate or move the xap file to 14 hive clientbin folder at the time of deploying the wsp in the testing server ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call context menu for you Sharepoint project in Visual Studio.
Then Add -> SharePoint Mapped Folder...
In the next window you can select TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ClientBin folder and add it into your project.
After that you can add subfolders or files to this ClientBin folder which will automaticaly deployed on server during wsp-file installation.